# Why are they choosing these particular dates in the episodes of Into the Dark?

Tags: into-the-dark

[Into the Dark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Into_the_Dark_(TV_series)#Episodes) is an American horror anthology web television series. The Tenth episode of the first season released on July 4th.

Until now each episode is on a particular day of the year, for example, the episode One is On Halloween, episode Two is On Thanksgiving, episode Three is On Christmas, and episode Ten is On Independence Day.

And all these days are in the order they come in a calendar.

Why are they choosing these particular days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a North American show, and these are all popular North American holidays. There are many horror movies where the story happens at/near one of these holidays (the Halloween franchise comes to mind).

Also according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Into_the_Dark_(TV_series))

> Each episode of the series is inspired by a holiday from the month in which it is released.